# How do I hide the page title based on node type using template_preprocess_page()?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7, this was possible. (See [How to hide page title based on node type using template_preprocess_page()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/43763).)

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == 'concert') {
    $variables['show_title'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

What is the equivalent in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 5):

**OUTDATED - please use [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145230/how-do-i-hide-the-page-title-based-on-node-type-using-template-preprocess-page/227833#227833) solution instead ...**

In D8 i used

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->getType() == 'page') {
        $variables['title'] = '';
    }
}
```

You still find the "node" object but you can't simply call the "type". The variable is protected, so you have to get the value via the function getType(). To get an overview install Devel and print with Kint the methods. This should only be a simple help, but maybe someone can deeper explain the concepts. Is it better to unset $variables['title'] in some way then to use $variables['title'] = ''?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @joekers it was not working for me either and had to use `theme_preprocess_page_title()` here is the details.  Put this in your `MY_THEME.theme` file or modify that function if it already exists.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if( $node->getType() == 'page' ) {
        $variables['title'] = "";
    }
}
```

To use it you might have to substitute the variable `page` with your content type machine name.

Comment: Thanks ... I used the page preprocess function in early D8 times - i'm shure the API has changed ...

Comment: One 'weird' thing I found is that if I have node revisions turned on and I enter a previous node revision page, the code suggested here has some undesired results. It will throw an exception like this: "Call to a member function getType() on string". It looks like that $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node') will deliver something which is not a node. By doing kat($node) on the result of the above code, I will actually get the node ID, not the node object itself. Let me know if my excplanation isn't clear enough. Thank you.

Comment: Have not tried it but you are probably right ... https://www.drupal.org/node/2495703 and follow to the duplicate issue ... its getting fixed

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this wasn't working for me in `theme_preprocess_page()` so I had to use `theme_preprocess_page_title()` as suggested by Twig debug.

Comment: Yes - there had been some progress since Jan 2015 ;) Maybe also interesting in this context: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187987/42095