# How to override page title by content type

Tags: theming, hooks, 8

I'm using the `pagetitle` core module to render a page title. However, for certain content types I want the <del>page</del> main title to be the **content type label** (e.g. "News") and not the **node label** (e.g. "Drupal 8 released!").

Is there a simple way to achieve it? My first guess was to use the `template_preprocess_page_title` but `$variables` has no context whatsoever about node, node type, etc...

Comment: what do you mean that when you visit a node, page title will show content type label  of this node?

Comment: When you visit a node the title of the page is the title of the node (e.g. "Drupal 8 released!". I want it to be the content type title (e.g. "News").

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As mentioned by Ivan Jaros You can use `hook_preprocess_page_title`.

You just have to load the node from the route first, to get some context.

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  // Load the node entity from current route
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {

    // Load the label of the bundle
    $bundle_label = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node_type')
      ->load($node->bundle())
      ->label();

    // Set the page title
    $variables['title'] = $bundle_label;
  }
}
```

If you just want to use this with certain content types, you can use `$node->bundle()` to get the machine-readable name and check against it.

Comment: This changes the title for the `block_title`. However it doesn't override the Page title. Any idea how to get the page title set to same value as the title block

Answer (score 5):

Linus got it right for the preprocess function, but I'd personally use this to get the current node (as it's shorter and seem easier...)

```
$node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')
```

Then to access the node title, use :

```
$title = $node->getTitle()
```

or to access another custom field (with a value) :

```
$node->get('field_MYFIELD')->value
```

Actually, access everything the way you'd access these datas in a regular node preprocess function :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module it is D8-ready already and supports what you need.

Comment: Although I am not 100% if it supports overriding title in the page title block. At this point I only know it works for page title.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ivan Jaros, as far as I can tell the supported page title is the one on the HTML head, I want to override the main title.

Comment: In that case hook_preprocess_page_title. Load the node from route, get the entitytype and get label from there.

Comment: This worked for me for the user profile page.

Answer (score 1):

Make a small module. Two files required:

File name: liveeventtitles.info.yml

```
name: Live Event Titles
description: Programmatically generates titles for event node bundles.
package: Custom
type: module
version: 1.0
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - node
```

File: liveeventtitles.module

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Modify the node create/edit form and automatically generate a node title for event nodes.
 */
define('LIVEEVENTTITLES_PLACEHOLDER', '%LiveEventTitle%');
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function liveeventtitles_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_event_form' || $form_id == 'node_event_edit_form') {
    $title_widget = &$form['title']['widget'][0];
    $default = (!empty($title_widget['value']['#default_value'])? $title_widget['value']['#default_value'] : LIVEEVENTTITLES_PLACEHOLDER);
    $title_widget['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
    $title_widget['value']['#type'] = 'value';
    $title_widget['value']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $form['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
/**
 * Implements hook_node_presave
 */
function liveeventtitles_node_presave(Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node) {
  $type = $node->getType();
  if ($type == 'event') {
    // Load the artist node to get the title
    if ($artist_id = $node->field_artist->getString()) {
      $artist = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($artist_id);
      $artist_name = $artist->title->getString();
    }
    // Load the Venue to get the title
    if ($venue_id = $node->field_venue->getString()) {
      $venue = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($venue_id);
      $venue_name = $venue->title->getString();
    }
    if (!empty($venue_name) && !empty($artist_name)) {
      $node->setTitle($artist_name . ' at ' . $venue_name);
    }
  }
}
```

I probably have more than I need, such as I don't think I need a default value and PLACEHOLDER in the hook_form_alter() but I need to give someone a reason to vote this down (-;

Answer (score 1):

In THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {} there is the $variables['head_title'] which is the highest hand - instance for the page title (Structured title: $variables['head_title_array'] ). There are also other interesting array keys like $variables['page']['content'] and $variables['node_type'] based on which the title can be processed.

Final thought: $variables['head_title'] = ['title_part1','title_part2']; since in the html.html.twig

```
<title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```