# How can I place the article date before the title?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm using the Basic theme and want to show the article date before the title. The problem is, that `{{ date }}` is only available in node.html.twig, whereas the title is created in page-tite.html.twig.

How can I place the article date before the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by implementing [template_preprocess_page_title()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) hook in your Theme (`THEME_NAME.theme`). Check example below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for page templates.
 */
function [THEME_NAME]_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  // Check if page is node page, and is instance of Node.
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface)) {
    // Get created time of Node and convert to human readable, and append Node title.
    $variables['title'] = '<span class="created-date">' . date("d m Y", $node->created->getValue()[0]['value']) . "</span> " . $node->getTitle();
  }
}
```

Similar question is answered by [@Linus](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/33762/linus)'s [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/187987/678).

Comment: I think it would be better to frame the date with tag to simplify setting of CSS styles.

Comment: Yes @YakimkinRoman, you're write. that would help style date differently. And since its a custom code we can alter it to match our needs. Thanks for pointing out, I'll update my answer with it.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantine I found the other answer too and combined it with another answer in the same thread:

Comment: `function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
   $variables['date_before'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($variables['node']->getCreatedTime(), 'long_date_without_time');
  }
}`

Comment: I changed the if condition `$node = Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')` back to your solution, because otherwise getCreatedTime() is throwing some null error when a page is restricted by Content Access module for whatever reason...

Answer (score 0):

I think, in Drupal 8 it would be not bad solution to define new block for it.
In this block one get value of date field and place this block before block with node title.

How to create block programmatically, you can see in a example of module [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).