# How can I override the search result page title dynamically?

Tags: 8, search

In my Drupal 8 site, I am using the default search page. If I enter a keyword, for example *article*, the search result will be listed under *Search result*.

I want to change that to *Search result for Article (keyword)*.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's the page title block. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/181828/15055 on how to set the page title. You maybe can use `hook_preprocess_page_title` to accomplish this by grabbing the query from the URL.

Comment: Yes, the page title is a block on Drupal 8. What the answers for the other question don't say is how to get the search parameters to use them in the title.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187934/how-to-override-page-title-by-content-type-in-drupal-8 Look for it.

Answer (score 7):

Here comes an example snippet on how to override the page title by URL query:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
  if ($current_path == '/search/node') {
    if (\Drupal::request()->query->has('keys')) {

      // Get the searched string.
      $keywords = \Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');

      // As of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/232304/15055 we probably
      // need to ensure the cache gets busted.
      $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url.query_args:keys';

      // Set the new title.
      $new_title = new \Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup('Search result for Article (@keywords)', ['@keywords' => $keywords]);
      $variables['title'] = $new_title;
    }
  }
}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

The hook mentioned above does not work in d8.Instead you can use hook_preprocess_page(&$variables).
Also you can use hook_preprocess_views_view(&$variables)
and continue with the same logic .
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

```
 $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
//echo $current_path;
if ($current_path == '/search/node') {
  if (\Drupal::request()->query->has('keys')) {
    $keywords = \Drupal::request()->query->get('keys');
    echo "Search Results for " . $keywords;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Why do you think `hook_preprocess_page_title()` would not work for Drupal 8? The search page isn't a view; a hook for a view would not have any effect.